# Correct way to filter out a specific key from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have this array of objects...

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "application": "Default Case Set",
    "errorSource": "CASEWORK",
    "message": 34,
    "stackTrace": 0,
    "date": 0,
    "user": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "application": "Default",
    "errorSource": "CASEWORK",
    "message": 39,
    "stackTrace": 2,
    "date": 0,
    "user": 0
   }
]
```

I would like to create an array of ids that looks like this...

```
[1, 2]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What's your best attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the `id` property value from each object.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "application": "Default Case Set",
    "errorSource": "CASEWORK",
    "message": 34,
    "stackTrace": 0,
    "date": 0,
    "user": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "application": "Default",
    "errorSource": "CASEWORK",
    "message": 39,
    "stackTrace": 2,
    "date": 0,
    "user": 0
   }
]

const result = arr.map(e => e.id)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!